# React/JS if and for conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a form and store it in an useState array, every time there is a change on "maritalStatus" of the  field and the status is 'Married' - I need to append the form so that the data I will store will store 2 persons details from the form (firstname/lastname/phone etc) if the status is other than 'Married' the data I store will only be for 1 person.

I am new to RN and I just can't handle this "IF" condition, would be glad if anyone can help.

Also in case the person selects - the children field and inputs a value( for example 2) the array should also be appended with 2 other fields and I will add later a fuction that will store this data on a remote server.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    Card,
    CardContent,
    Container,
    Grid,
    TextField,
    FormControl,
    InputLabel,
    MenuItem,
    Select,
    FormControlLabel,
    RadioGroup,
    Radio,
    FormLabel
  } from '@mui/material';
  import { Box } from '@mui/system';


function AddForm() {
    const defaultData = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName:'',
        email:'',
        childrens:'',
        gender:'Male',
        participation:'Yes',
        phone1:'',
        phone2:'',
        phone3:'',
        maritalStatus:'',
    }
    const [applicant, setApplicant] = useState([{ ...defaultData }]);

    const onChange = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const data = [...applicant];
        data[index][name] = value;
        setApplicant(data);
      };
      const onChildrensChange = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const data = [...applicant];
        data[index][name] = value;
        setApplicant(data)
        setApplicant([...applicant, { ...defaultData }]);
      };
      let onMaritalStatusChange = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const data = [...applicant];
        data[index][name] = value;
        setApplicant(data)
        if(e.maritalStatus === 'Married'){
            setApplicant([...applicant, { ...defaultData }]);
        }
      };
    const onAddClick = () => {
        setApplicant([...applicant, { ...defaultData }]);
    };
        return (
            <Container>
                <Card>
                    <CardContent>
                        {applicant.map((element, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextField
                                            label="First Name"
                                            name="firstName"
                                            value={element.firstName}
                                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e, index)}
                                            fullWidth
                                        />                      
                                        <TextField
                                            label="Last name"
                                            name="lastName"
                                            value={element.lastName}
                                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e, index)}
                                            fullWidth
                                        />
                                        <TextField
                                            label="Email"
                                            name="email"
                                            value={element.email}
                                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e, index)}
                                            fullWidth
                                        />
                                        <TextField
                                            label="childrens"
                                            name="childrens"
                                            value={element.childrens}
                                            onChange={(e) => onChildrensChange(e, index)}
                                            fullWidth
                                        />
                                        
                                        <FormControl fullWidth>
                                        <InputLabel>Gender</InputLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            label="gender"
                                            name='gender'
                                            fullWidth
                                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e, index)}
                                            defaultValue='Male'
                                        >
                                            <MenuItem value={'Male'}>Male</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'Female'}>Female</MenuItem>
                                        </Select>
                                        </FormControl>

                                        <FormControl fullWidth>
                                        <InputLabel>Marital Status</InputLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            label="maritalStatus"
                                            name='maritalStatus'
                                            fullWidth
                                            onChange={(e) => onMaritalStatusChange(e, index)}
                                            defaultValue='Single'
                                        >
                                            <MenuItem value={'SINGLE'}>Single</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'Married'}>Married</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'Divorced'}>Divorced</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'Widowed'}>Widowed</MenuItem>
                                        </Select>
                                        </FormControl>

                                        <FormControl>
                                            <FormLabel>Participation</FormLabel>
                                            <RadioGroup
                                                defaultValue="female"
                                                name="participation"
                                                onChange={(e) => onChange(e, index)}
                                            >
                                                <FormControlLabel value="Yes" control={<Radio />} label="Yes" />
                                                <FormControlLabel value="No" control={<Radio />} label="No" />
                                            </RadioGroup>
                                        </FormControl>    
                                        <TextField
                                            label="Phone"
                                            name="phone1"
                                            value={element.phone1}
                                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e, index)}
                                            fullWidth
                                        />                                    
                                        <TextField
                                            label="Phone"
                                            name="phone2"
                                            value={element.phone2}
                                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e, index)}
                                            fullWidth
                                        /> 
                                        <TextField
                                            label="Phone"
                                            name="phone3"
                                            value={element.phone3}
                                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e, index)}
                                            fullWidth
                                        /> 
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            )
                        })}
                        <Box mt={5}>{JSON.stringify(applicant)}</Box>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
            </Container>
        )
}


export default AddForm;
```

```js
import './App.css';
import AddForm from './AddForm';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddForm/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: let onMaritalStatusChange = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const data = [...applicant];
        data[index][name] = value;
        setApplicant(data)
        if(e.maritalStatus === 'Married'){
            setApplicant([...applicant, { ...defaultData }]);
        }
      };

I guess this is not the proper way of doing it as the condition is not verified

Answer (score 0):

Define a key like "spouse" with object type value on defaultData object.
Have the spouse form details defined just beneath the "maritalStatus" select dropdown.
Use conditional rendering for spouse form like below

```
{ element.maritalStatus === "Married" && (
  // write the spouse form here
)}
```

So, as soon as you update the state with maritalStatus and it is "Married", the spouse form details would be rendered.

You can do the same for children forms too.

Comment: not sure I understood it correctly, could you provide an example? I am relatively new in react.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking e. maritalStatus. Instead you should check e.target.value or, in your case, as you are already destructuring the value, you can directly check the value

```
if(value==="Married"){ // write your code over here}
```

Also to solve this problem you need to play with the Applicant state where on the basis of children and married you can show the form.

```html
const Myform = () => {
  const defaultData = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    childrens: "",
    gender: "Male",
    participation: "Yes",
    phone1: "",
    phone2: "",
    phone3: "",
    maritalStatus: ""
  };
  const [applicant, setApplicant] = React.useState(defaultData);
  const handleChildern = (e) => {
    const udatedApplicant = { ...applicant };
    udatedApplicant.childrens = e.target.value;
    setApplicant({ ...udatedApplicant });
  };
  const handleRadio = (e) => {
    const udatedApplicant = { ...applicant };
    udatedApplicant.maritalStatus = e.target.value;
    setApplicant({ ...udatedApplicant });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div onChange={handleRadio}>
        <label htmlFor="Married">Married</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Married" name="marStatus" value="Married" />
        <label htmlFor="single">Single</label>
        <input type="radio" id="single" name="marStatus" value="Single" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="children">children</label>
        <input type="text" id="children" onChange={handleChildern} />
      </div>

      {applicant.maritalStatus === "Married" && <RenderSpouse />}
      {Number(applicant.childrens) > 0 && (
        <RenderChildren numberOfChildren={applicant.childrens} />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const RenderSpouse = () => {
  return <div>Hi I am spouse</div>;
};

const RenderChildren = ({ numberOfChildren }) => {
  const [childrens, setChildrens] = React.useState(
    new Array(Number(numberOfChildren)).fill("")
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const newChildren = new Array(Number(numberOfChildren)).fill("");
    setChildrens(newChildren);
  }, [numberOfChildren]);
  return (
    <>
      {childrens.map((_, index) => {
        return <div key={index}>children {index}</div>;
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

So with this approach your form would be more generic to solve this problem

[Working Code Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-night-dxxe3j?file=/src/App.js:258-2086)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: let onMaritalStatusChange = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const data = [...applicant];
        data[index][name] = value;
        setApplicant(data)
        if(value === 'Married'){
            setApplicant([...applicant, { ...defaultData.maritalStatus='Married'}]);
        } else {
            applicant.length > 0 && applicant.length !== 1 && (
            data.splice(index, 1));
        }
    }

I managed to solved(not the best solution) for this IF condition, but now I am stuck on the FOR loop for 'children'

Comment: let onChildrensChange = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const data = [...applicant];
        data[index][name] = value;
        setApplicant(data)
        for (var i=1; i<=value; i++ ){
            // console.log(data)
            setApplicant([...applicant, { ...defaultData }]);
        }
    }

Here is the code for the onchildrenschange - I used a loop, I guess I still a key/value thing, as advised by the warning.
any help would be appreciated

And once launched I only get 1 children on my list no matter the input number

Comment: setState is batch and async so it will not work like this, what you can do update the applicant state and play with it, then it would be more generic like following working example for your problem statement where dynamically rendering children and spouse based on the user input


https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-night-dxxe3j?file=/src/App.js


hope this helps, you can have a sense of logic and idea